# Nuget : how to NOT remove old packages after package update?

Tags: git, module, nuget, nuget-package

A couple months ago we've started using Nuget in our ASP.NET MVC projects. We're building a lot of applications that consist of several reusable compontents. For example:

Application A
- Authentication Module (nuget package with JavaScript/Templates/Controllers/POCO)
- Payment Module (nuget package with JavaScript/Templates/Controllers/POCO)

Application B
- Authentication Module (nuget package with JavaScript/Templates/Controllers/POCO)

But our team has grown a lot the last weeks and we're experiencing some problems when merging packages. Everytime we update a package, the old version package is removed from the package folder. This is great, but it causes a lot of problems when merging/checkin into git (we use tortoiseGit). For Example:

Developer 1 updates the Authentication module in Application A to version 2.0 and checks this in. Developer 2 is also working on Application A and updates the Authentication module to version 2.1. Developer 1 checks in before Developer 2. When Developer 2 pulls the latest changes from git and tries to checkin his changes he will experience a lot of conflicts in the nuget packages folder because he doesnt have the files from version 2.0  in his package folder (TortoiseGit Error: FileNotFound). Now Developer 1 has to create the package folder in his local file system and mark it as deleted to be able to checkin in his changes.

**This problem would be resolved if Nuget doesn't delete old package folders on an update. Is this possible?** In this scenario we would of course clean up old packages in the nuget package folder manually...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a better solution for your team would be to not include the *packages* folder in version control, and instead [enable package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).

[If you use Nuget 2.7+ , visit this site](http://docs.nuget.org/Consume/Package-Restore)